# Add random value from array to a css property

Tags: javascript, css

Html code:

```
    <h1><a>Minimalist Website</a></h1>
    <h1><a>Fast Food</a></h1>
```

Javascript code:

```
var colors = ['#000','#111', '#222']; 
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
document.querySelector('#menu h1 a:hover').style.cssText= 'text-shadow: random_color + 0px 0px 1px, + random_color + 0px 0px 1px';
```

What I am trying to do is:

(1) generate a colour from the array.

(2) put that colour into the text-shadow.

What's happening is that the random_colour value taken from the array is not showing up. I've looked at the css and there is no sign of the text-shadow applied.

Comment: And what's not working for you?

Comment: As far as I know you can't catch pseudo classes with selectors.

Comment: random_color is in the string

Comment: @Kinduser two issues, 1) he needs to use `mouseover` event, 2) he needs to loop the array of elements and attach that event to each one of them

Comment: @Mr.Alien Looking forward for your answer.

Comment: @Kinduser someone answered already.. anyways.. Sean Poh -> with events https://jsfiddle.net/z4dzpqc7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, in addition to a few other things:

1. You are looking for `#menu` which I can't see in the **HTML**.
2. You need to use `querySelectorAll`, to get multiple elements.
3. Your selector also looks for `:hover`, but hover is a state of something and not something you can select upon as a query to the DOM.

Try this code:

```
var colors = ['red','green', 'blue']; 
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
var items = document.querySelectorAll('h1 a');

items.forEach(item => {
    item.style.cssText = 'text-shadow: ' + random_color + ' 10px 10px 0px';
});
```

I changed a few things to make it clearer, but hopefully you can adapt it to your needs.

You can play with it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/fy0893mm/

Additionally, if you wanted each item to be its own random colour, simply move the random variable into the loop of items.

```
var colors = ['red','green', 'blue']; 
var items = document.querySelectorAll('h1 a');

items.forEach(item => {
    var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    item.style.cssText = 'text-shadow: ' + random_color + ' 10px 10px 0px';
});
```

Also, because you were trying to select `:hover`, it made me wonder if you wanted this to occur on hover of the element, if so, try this code which will attach the appropriate event listeners to each item.

```
var colors = ['red','green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'orange']; 
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
var items = document.querySelectorAll('h1 a');

items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    item.style.cssText = 'text-shadow: ' + random_color + ' 10px 10px 0px';
  });
  item.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    item.style.cssText = 'text-shadow: none';
  });
});
```

Comment: It is better if you use `textShadow` so that he doesn't replace entire inline style..  also, added events for the same - https://jsfiddle.net/z4dzpqc7/

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the answer. I just realised that you changed your answer!! Thanks so much!! I'll keep in mind that you can't really select css psuedo elements. Thanks so much Michael!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('#menu h1 a:hover').style.cssText= 'text-shadow: ' + random_color + '0px 0px 1px, ' + random_color + '0px 0px 1px';
```

Comment: (missing space before 0?)

Comment: Also add explanation as to what and why have you changed

Comment: That's great but I think as @Kind user said, you can't catch pseudo classes with selectors apparently.